# webservices with mysql in android

Tags: android, mysql, web-services

I wish to know about how to call webservices in android i had done a lot of serach google and have read several tutorilals but was not able to understand much and manipulate, can anyone suggst any good Tutorial, or provide any Pdf file or any book related to web services so that i can understand it.plz provide easy step by step tutorial for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some resources are enlisted below.

SOAP webservices: Example using kSOAP2

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

JSON webservices: Example with 4 different parsers

https://github.com/martinadamek/json-android-compare